# Tomcat SSL configuration for JSSE - what is sslProtocol attribute

Tags: ssl, configuration, tomcat7, java-7, jsse

**Spec:**

Tomcat 7.0.52
Java 7.0_60

**Intro:**

In order to configure Tomcat to support secure connection we must configure *Connector* element in *server.xml* file.
First of all we must choose implementation of SSL. Let's asume we use JSSE.
When JSSE implementation is used then we can configure SSL protocol using two attributes:

- *sslEnabledProtocols*
- *sslProtocol*

**Frustration:**

It does not seem that sslProtocol attribute does anything. It looks like it is a dead completely. Only *sslEnabledProtocols* can influence used protocol.

For example :

```xml
<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true"
    ...
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    sslProtocol="SSLv3"/>
```

Value *SSLv3* won't change anything. If browser supports TLS1.2 then TLS1.2 will be used, if browser supports onlu TLS1.0 then TLS1.0 will be used. So this value changes nothing for me. Only value of *sslEnabledProtocols* matters.

**Question:**

Could someone explain meaning of *sslProtocol* attribute? And when to use it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Value SSLv3 won't change anything. If browser supports TLS1.2 then TLS1.2 will be used, if browser supports onlu TLS1.0 then TLS1.0 will be used.

That's not correct. If you set the `sslProtocol` to `SSLv3`, only `SSLv3` will be used, and specifically no versions of TLS will be used. It's better not to specify this attribute at all: that way you use all the possible SSL/TLS versions supported by the version of JSSE you're using.

Comment: I have tested this. For example with IE and Chrome. It looks like lack of explicity set sslEnabledProtocols means that all protcols are enabled by default. So the highest supported protocol is used. If browser support only TLS1.0 then TLS1.0 is chosen, if browser supports TLS1.2 then TLS1.2 is chosen. sslProtocol changes nothing. I'm not going to set this configuration anywhere, it is just an example. I can just change sslEnabledProtocols to 'SSLv3' and then every browser uses SSLv3.